# Why does pip freeze geneate package_name=0.0.0

Tags: pip

I used pip freeze to pull out every dependency of my virtualenv to use this environment in other place so that I got the requirements.txt like the below.

```
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
get==0.0.0
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.12
idna==2.6
numpy==1.13.3
pandas==0.20.3
post==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
public==0.0.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
query-string==0.0.0
request==0.0.0
requests==2.18.4
setupfiles==0.0.50
six==1.11.0
sqlalchemy==1.1.14
urllib3==1.22
```

I used this requirements in other computer but whenever I tried running pip install -r requirements.txt I got the error like the following.

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: certifi==2017.7.27.1 in d:\workspace\juice-project\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.0.4 in d:\workspace\juice-project\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting get==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached get-0.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "d:\workspace\juice-project\venv\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\verys\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-1cd8yl0b\\get\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\verys\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1cd8yl0b\get\
```

I thought it is caused by privilege of window user so that I spent a lots of time to solve this problem with other reason. I got so annoyed because of the bug. Could you explain why this unused things generate and why this error can be like this?

Comment: In addition to the answer, a question: Have you really installed and do you really use these `get`/`request`/`setupfiles`? Or did you tried to install `requests`, but just mistyped? Then consider your computer as potentially hacked and infected. It was difficult for me to decipher these libraries, and probably it was done intentionally by the author to hide the malicious code. Read this on how such attacks are performed: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/09/19/pypi-python-repository-hit-by-typosquatting-sneak-attack/

Comment: @SergeyVasilyev I used requests in my original virtualenv and there was no problem about that. But I ran this environment behind proxy in my company. I have been using this requirements after deleting every lines ending with 0.0.0.

Comment: This is the difference here: `requests` is okay, `request` is not. The former is a well-known library, the latter is probably a malicious package (due to how cryptic it is from inside, and how much extra *bash* logic it executes on install via `setup.py`). It is enough to mistype only once to get the latter and its dependencies into your virtualenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these libraries — `get`, `request` (of the same author) — are written improperly. It is not your problem, it is theirs. You are NOT able to solve this from your side.

Take a look at their [`setup.py`](https://github.com/russianidiot/get.py/blob/master/setup.py):

```
kwargs = dict()

# known-issues:
# pip running `python setup.py egg_info` before installation:
# 1) pip checks metadata name pip/req/req_install.py:run_egg_info()
# 2) pip attempts to discover all of the dependencies before installation
name = os.path.basename(os.getcwd()).split(".")[0].lower()

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "requirements.txt")
if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isfile(path):
    kwargs["install_requires"] = open(path).read().splitlines()

setup(name=name, **kwargs)
```

It does not contain `version=...` kwarg. Sadly so, this library will be **always** of version 0.0.0, which is the default of this `setupfiles` self-made library (see [here](https://github.com/russianidiot/setupfiles.py/blob/master/packages/setupfiles/dist.py#L49)).

**PS:** Do you really want to use a library of that quality? Why not just copy thise [few lines](https://github.com/russianidiot/get.py/blob/master/py_modules/get.py) to your code? This is not nodejs world, where it is good to use nano-modules like this.

---

**UPD:** I've just noticed that `setup()` is not from `setuptools`, but from [`setupfiles`](http://setupfiles), also of the same author, and it is declared to guess the values of the keys. So, maybe it was supposed to work. But is broken because of this non-standard usage of the setup conventions.

I wouldn't say it is a best or even good practice to replace `setuptools` this way. And it is not safe either — the malicious library authors can just inject any arbitrary code to be executed on your workstations/servers. Especially [that hacky](https://github.com/russianidiot/setupfiles.py/blob/master/setupfiles.py).

Still, in the example it requires a `version=...` argument, which is missing in those libraries.